# Banner covers UIActionSheet in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet, banner, revmob

I have a RevMob banner in Swift, its working perfectly but when opening an UIActionSheet the cancel button gets covered by the advertisement, this also happens with GameCenter , what should I do to fix it?

My code:

```
func appearAd(){

    if revMobSession == true{
        RevMobAds.session().showBanner()

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have  you tried moving or hiding it when the action sheet come up?

Comment: @DavidSkrundz I really don't  want to hide it but moving it could be an option.